# How does comments ordering work?

Tags: discussion, comments

I was reading the first 5 comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728809/search-integer-in-array-formed-by-joining-two-sorted-arrays), and was wondering about the argument of the fifth commentator. It seems like he quoted a sentence which somehow does not exist.

[image: Before expanding]

Then I clicked '*show 3 more comments*' and found out that the OP comment was hidden.

[image]

How does the ordering of comments (before clicking 'show X more comments') work? Obviously, it's not by time or the number of votes ...

Comment: It is by time **and** number of votes. There is space for a limited number of comments; when space is short, comments with more votes can bump out 'late' comments without votes.

Comment: Putting it differently: The 3 comments with votes are displayed, there is space for more comments, so the two oldest comments without votes are included too. The displayed comments are ordered by time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rules for comment display priority are:

- Always show the *highest-voted* comments *in chronological order*
- In the event of a vote-tie, give priority to older comments

We can see that in practice here:

- Start with the highest-voted (here, score-3) comment

  ```
  [score-3 comment]
  ```
- Add the next-highest comment. Two comments are tied for second place (each with score of 1). We give preference to the older comment:

  ```
  [score-1 comment]
  [score-3 comment]
  ```
- Since we have more slots, add the more recent second-place score-1 comment:

  ```
  [score-1 comment]
  [score-3 comment]
  [score-1 comment]
  ```
- All of the score-0 comments are tied for third place, so we add them in chronological order until we run out of spots:

  ```
  [score-1 comment]
  [score-0 comment]
  [score-0 comment]
  [score-3 comment]
  [score-1 comment]
  ```

We have run out of spots, so all other comments are hidden, including the score-0 comment before the score-3 comment.